# Java getting data from multiple items of ListView

Tags: java, listview, javafx, error-handling

To return the item selected from a ListView in Java, I would use this code:

```
listview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

However, if my ListView allows multiple selection, I can't find a direct way to return all of the items selected in the ListView.
Is there a straightforward approach to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `getSelectedItems()` method of the `SelectionModel` that should do what you want.  It returns an observable list - so you can monitor it for changes with a `ListChangedLister`.

```
    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    listView.setItems(list);
    list.add("Item 1");
    list.add("Item 2");
    list.add("Item 3");

    List<String> selected = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
```